# Joining multiple text fields and keeping everything..

Tags: linux, bash, join, awk

I have about a dozen files formatted like:

```
file1:
david@example.com:DSL
jacob@example.com:FIOS
stephen@example.com:DSL

file2: 
david@example.com:webspace
jacob@example.com:webspace
randy@example.com:webspace

file3:
david@example.com:www
randy@example.com:android
```

I'd like them the whole thing to end up something like

```
david@example.com:DSL:webspace:www
jacob@example.com:FIOS:webspace
stephen@example.com:DSL
randy@example.com:webspace:android
```

I'm pretty weak on shell script text processing so I've been playing with various chained and iterated permutations of GNU join -a and not getting everything. I don't care if the data stays sorted on the first field, but I'd like the order of the other fields to stay intact; if it was encountered first, it should be up first.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Do your own attempt and post the code, including desired and current behavior.

Comment: @JimTuck Just post some attempt, that's all we ask :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to generate outer join of three or more files with `join`.
Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash             # use the variable hash as an associative array
IFS=:                       # set the delimiter to ":"

for file in $@; do          # loop over the specified files
    while read line || [ -n "${line}" ]; do
        set -- $line        # split the line with ":"
        hash[$1]+=":$2"     # append the 2nd field to a hash keyed by the 1st field
    done < $file
done

for key in ${!hash[@]}; do  # loop over the hash keys
    echo "${key}${hash[$key]}"
done
```

The usage is to save the code above as a script and say: `./thisscript file1 file2 file3 ...`.